# This function returns null. I am using mongoDB and node and bluebird for promises

Tags: nodes, bluebird

This is function which is supposed to return one document with the given id:

```
function detailed(code,callback){
    MongoClient.connectAsync(murl).then(function(db) {
        return db.collection('reports').find({'_id':code});
    }).then(function(reports) {
        callback(null, reports)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        callback(err, null);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not a mongo realated issue.
I think you have just missed the return statement of the detailed function.

try

```
function detailed(code,callback){

 return MongoClient.connectAsync(murl).then(function(db){

 return db.collection('reports').find({'_id':code});
 }).then(function(reports) {
    callback(null, reports)
 }).catch(function(err) {
     callback(err, null);
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `promisifyAll` in bluebird you need to add `Async` as a suffix to all method calls. You're calling `find` which is not a bluebird method - use `.findAsync`.

In addition, if you need to work with callbacks don't use `.then(...).catch(...)` use `asCallback(callback)`